How do I Disable VLAN's for OpenWRT 23
I have a Linksys WRT1900AC router with openwrt 23 that I am trying to connect to my fibre internet. For the configuration to work my ISP has stated that I need to disable VLAN's. When I look at the settings on their provided router there is a specific button that disables VLAN

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in OpenWRT?

If you can’t find an option to disable it there is a good case OpenWRT doesn’t by default support VLAN, I used it for a half decade, I don’t recall it supporting VLANs. I can think of a lot of reasons OpenWRT would be difficult to configure for fiber mostly connected to the fact the device unlikely has support for the required fiber SFP ONT device. It does appear it supports it but it being enabled unlikely would cause it your fiber connection not to work. Here is some information. It appears it’s effectively disabled by default

With OpenWRT you have to specifically set up VLAN (there is no enable/disable as such) - so, whatever your issue is, it's nothing to do with VLAN - by the way, what you do with the LAN side regarding VLAN has naff all to do with your ISP, they wouldn't have a clue if you have VLANs on your LAN or not.
